# Displaying an array comma-separated in jade?

Tags: html, node.js, pug

I want to display an array in Jade separated by commas instead of line which I currently have how can I do this? This is segment of code I need help with players being the array passed from javascript

```
p Currently playing:
  ul
    each theExit in players
      p #{theExit}
```

Comment: Can you include an example of the value for `players`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `players` is an array of `String`'s you can use following statement:

```
p Currently playing: #{players.join(', ')}
```

That will give you something like (assuming you had 3 entries in the array: `player1`, `player2` and `player3`):

```
<p>Currently playing: player1, player2, player3</p>
```

I hope that will help.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an array of objects and you want a comma-separated list of a property of each object, I went with:

```
- var playerList = players.map(player => player.name).join(', ')
p Currently playing: #{playerList}
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposed you were working with not plain `String` arrays and your data is something like below:

```
{
  [_id: 1, name: 'player1'],
  [_id: 2, name: 'player2'],
  [_id: 3, name: 'player3'],
}
```

Then you could probably just use:

```
each player, index in players
  if index === players.length -1
    | #{players.name}
  else
    | #{players.name},
```

NOTE: Not really the cleanest solution out there but does the job. Use at your own disposal. :)